# Trying to use multiple component for a single path

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a react app and I have several components I want to use on my root path. I wonder what are best practices as far as rendering then on one component and then linking that component to my root or if I could add all components to my root path.

I want to add 3 other components to root path.

This is my app.js file:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Header from "./components/Header";
import EyewearTitle from "./components/EyewearTitle";

import Buy from "./components/Buy";
import './App.css';

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <Header />
                <Route exact path="/" component={EyewearTitle} />
                <Route exact path="/buy" component={Buy} />
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: By saying "root path" you mean EyewearTitle component? Do you want to use those several components there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add all components you want to render under a single component. For example, I might use a `<ShoppingScreen/>` component, and on that screen, would render:

```
render() {
  return(
    <div className="shopping-screen">
      <ShoppingScreenSideBar/>
      <ShoppingScreenItems/>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Okay yeah I figured that would be best just wasn't too sure. I would then want to use that component on my root path right?

Comment: Yes, so it would look like `<Route exact path="/" component={ParentComponent} />`

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for helping me clear that up. ^_^v